# I can't go any further because my rad suits are only level 2

Tags: wasteland-2

I have visited the Ag Center, Highpool, the Rail Camp.  I have visited a few shrines and even one cache in the radiation.

It seems I can't get to any new places.  All I can do is wander around and get attacked by three-man bandit teams or six-lizard gila monster teams.

I have radiation suits.  They are low-quality and allow the team to survive level 1 and level 2 radiation clouds.

I could just use the Ranger editor to get high-level radiation suits, but there must be some way to do this without using the Ranger editor.

Am I just supposed to wander around until I discover high-level Radiation suits on the bodies of bandits?

Update: I have some spoiler-heavy insights:

> There are two sets of turrets; one big and one small.
>  To attack the big turrets directly is suicidal; the small turrets are weak.
>  The small turrets are located in the "Prison Valley" and they protect "Red" the merchant.  They are basically white or silver.  They have about 100 hit points.
>  The big turrets are black and huge and mounted on buildings in the actual 
>  "Prison" map.  They are behind a row 
>  of white stones and an intercom.  As you approach, Danforth speaks to the party 
>  from the intercom.  The big black turrets have thousands of hit points.
>  It is not necessary to attack the small white turrets to get to Red, but it is 
>  the easiest approach.  The other approach is to explore the entire map until
>  you find the back door to Red's hideout.
>  Note that after you talk to Red, you still have to explore the Citadel to locate
>  the quest target.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a quest that gives you a +4 radiation suit, to start it go to the prison camp and find Red iirc. then go back to RC and follow quest from there.

Comment: Thanks. Currently my rep is too low to vote you up, but your feedback gave me enough clues to find the following. [link to walkthrough that might refer to beta, not to final release of game](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2014-09-19-wasteland-2-walkthrough-and-game-guide?page=7) I guess I am going to have to face down those turrets at the prison.  I had caught sight of them before and decided that there was no chance of beating them, but possibly with LAW rockets I could do it.

Comment: Just FYI, you don't have to kill the turrets yet, you come back to that later if you want it to be easier. Go to titain :).

Comment: You definitely don't need to go near the turrets to get the +4 rad suits.

Comment: Also if you fix the radio tower in the first quest, it'll be repeating morse code that mentions these suits.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the quest to find Damonta?

> IIRC, it tells you to ask around the prison. Pretty much anyone you ask will point you towards Red. They will all have different codes to disable Red's turrets. None work.
>  Near the gate with turrets leading to Red there is an intercom. It will ask for your "preferred customer code" or something. The code is "rosebud". It's a keypad like a phone, press the numbers that correspond to the letters.

Alternately:

> You can go through the cave at the back, which has a bunch of critters in it. If you do fight the turrets, someone with high Computer Science can reprogram them during combat if you are fast enough to run up and do it.

Now you can go in and speak to him.

> Red tells you to speak to a guy called Baychowski who has been arrested by the Rangers. He is in the jail back at Ranger Citadel. Speak to the Prison Guard to wake him up. Now you can speak to Baychowski. You can offer him freedom if he leads you to the suits. He will agree, and put an RV on your world map. Head over, grab the suits, and either release or betray Baychowski. Of course, Vargas will be pissed if you let him escape.

And now you have +4 Radiation suits.

Answer (score 0):

Killing Red is also a way of getting a +4 suit.